# How to implement optional chaining / checking nested object properties using VanillaJS or Lodash

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, lodash, babeljs

I'm looking for the solution to rewrite below code:

```
data && data[name] && data[name].accounts[0] && data[name].accounts[0][user[userName]] && ...
```

As far I know, there is lodash **_.get** method but how to use dynamic properties like name, userName etc. without loosing code readability?

I have found also **babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining** but latest release of mentioned package is named as alfa version. It doesnt seem to be good for big PROD project purposes.

Any other ideas of how to write such syntax ?
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with lodash's get

Comment: What has template literals concept to do when checking nested object properties ?

Comment: Have added an answer using template literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what the data structure looks like from the question, especially that last bit: `user[userName]`. Say the data structure looked like this:

```
let name = 'angelos';
let userName = 'epithemiou'

let data = {
    angelos: {
        accounts: [
            {
                epithemiou: 'Hello there'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then with template literals and lodash's get function you could do this:

```
let result = _.get(data, `${name}.accounts[0].${userName}`);
```

Comment: That's probably "Euthymiou" rather than "epithemiou" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, how about a function that takes an object and a path passed in as separate arguments and then uses a loop to either return the object at the end of the path or `undefined` if the path doesn't exist?

```js
function getField(obj, ...path){
  if(!obj)
    return undefined;
  let curr = obj;
  for(let i = 0; i < path.length; i++){
    curr = curr[path[i]];
    if(typeof curr == "undefined" || curr == null)
      return undefined;
  }
  return curr;
}

// our data object
let data = {
  henry : {
    accounts : [{dude : "Hello World" }]
  },
  greg : {
    accounts : []
  }
}

// our search terms
let name = "henry",
  username = "dude";



console.log(getField(data, name, "accounts", 0, username)) // Hello World

console.log(getField(data, "greg", "accounts", 0, username)) // Undefined

console.log(getField(data, "shrek", "accounts")) // Undefined
```

To make it more "readable" you could perhaps take a string as the path and then parse/split it by a character such as a '.' or '/', then pass in dynamic variables using a template literal.

```js
function getField(obj, path){
  path = path.split(".");
  if(!obj)
    return undefined;
  let curr = obj;
  for(let i = 0; i < path.length; i++){
    curr = curr[path[i]];
    if(typeof curr == "undefined" || curr == null)
      return undefined;
  }
  return curr;
}

// our data object
let data = {
  henry : {
    accounts : [{dude : "Hello World" }]
  },
  greg : {
    accounts : []
  }
}

// our search terms
let name = "henry",
  username = "dude";



console.log(getField(data, `${name}.accounts.0.${username}`)) // Hello World
```